# How to make JButton with transparent icon and non-transparent text?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, transparency

I need to make a JButton with an image icon and regular text. This question is not duplicate of [How to make JButton with transparent background and regular text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581446/how-to-make-jbutton-with-transparent-background-and-regular-text), as I need to upload an image as icon and make it transparent as well. I tried to use overriden paintComponent() method

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
        java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
        super.paintComponent(g2);
    }
```

But all it does is paints icon and text both transparent, also button does not refresh properly.
Are there any possible workarounds?

**UPDATE**

The way I am setting the button is the following (item.getImage() returns array of bytes):

```
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusPainted(true);
        setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        if(item.getImage() != null) {
            int w = BUTTON_SIZE - 10;
            int h = BUTTON_SIZE - 10;

            if(menuItem.isShowImageOnly()) {
                setIcon(menuItem.getScaledImage(w, h));
            }
            else {
                w = 80;
                h = 40;

                setIcon(menuItem.getScaledImage(w, h));
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draw the transparency on the Image first

```
    Image im = ...;
    java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) im.getGraphics();
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
    g2.drawImage(0,0, im, null);
    g2.dispose();
    ImageIcon icon = ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood properly - should I add this code just before calling the setIcon() method? If I try to do so all I get are no buttons at all.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea - before setIcon. Since you haven't pasted any code showing how you are creating the button(s), I can't comment on the problem you are reporting

Comment: I've updated the post - added code showing how the buttons are created. Can you comment more, please, regarding the code?

Comment: What class is menuItem?