# How to make JRadioButton transparent

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I want to make the white circles of JRadioButtons transparent. 
How can I do that? `setOpaque(false)` only removes the background from text and not the circle.

Comment: You have to play with the alpha channel.

Comment: @RomanC ok but how do i change the fill color of the circle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent JButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585867/transparent-jbutton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom Icons that use transparency for the radio button. See methods like:

```
setIcon(...);
setSelectedIcon(...);
```

Comment: I put blank 10x10 px .png file as icon, but this also removed the circle (border). Is there any way to keep it or I just have to draw it on the icon?

Comment: You need to create a custom Icon that draws everything the way you want it to appear and you need to set transparent pixels where you want the icon to be transparent. These Icons replace the default Icons used by the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

```
jRadioButton1.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: this will hide the whole button and I only want to remove the background