# JButton with no background

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Thank you for your kind, we learned from you many times.
I have `xJButton` class inherits `JButton` class.

I am doing this to add an image as icon and change it after it clicked.

I do not want the blue color to be as background and also i don't want any border on it.

Everything is working vine, except the border.

You can see there is 2 borders

[image]

```
setOpaque(false);
setContentAreaFilled(false);
setBackground(null);
```

can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent JButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585867/transparent-jbutton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
xJButton.setBorder(null);
xJButton.setBorderPainted(false);
xJButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
xJButton.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad I could help you . Btw an upvote would be gratefully received for a struggling junior such as myself :)