# Let the transparent part of the image on a button be transparent

Tags: java, swing, background, awt, transparent

I'm using 2 pictures, one of these is the background of the screen and the other one is the background of a button. The image of the button is transparent in some parts. I'd like it to cover the background image on the transparent parts

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oDSE.jpg), but it doesn't. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHi0j.jpg).

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class TryOut1 extends JFrame
{

   public TryOut1()
   {
       screen();
       buttonDoor();

       setSize(1280,1024); 
   }

   public void screen(){
       setSize(1280,1024);

       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setVisible(true);
       setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Ziegel4.jpg")));
       setLayout(new FlowLayout());

       setSize(1280,1024);
   }

   public void buttonDoor(){
       JButton b1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Tor2.png"));
       b1.setEnabled(true);
       b1.setVisible(true);
       b1.setBackground(new Color( 0, 0, 0, 0) );


       add(b1);

       b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           dispose();
       }
       });
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        new TryOut1();
    }
}
```

How would I be able to make the transparent parts of the image actually transparent

Thank u for ur help in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a `JLabel`, adding the background image to it, and then add this label to your content pane is not the best approach. The label will be treated as a component and all other components won't be oriented properly by the layout manager.

You should draw the background image of your content pane by overriding `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method as shown [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125707/simplest-way-to-set-image-as-jpanel-background)

Then change the proper properties of your `JButton` and make it transparent as shown [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585867/transparent-jbutton)

All of these in an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
public class TryOut1 extends JFrame {

    public TryOut1() {
        try {
            screen();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buttonDoor();

        setSize(1280, 1024);
    }

    public void screen() throws IOException {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        File backgroundImg = new File(desktop, "background.png");
        Image img = ImageIO.read(backgroundImg);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    public void buttonDoor() {
        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        File doorFile = new File(desktop, "door.png");
        JButton b1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon(doorFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        b1.setOpaque(false);
        b1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        b1.setBorderPainted(false);
        add(b1);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // All swing apps must run in their own thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TryOut1().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

**Preview:** (ignore the white space at right, my background image is small)

[image: preview]

Comment: `all other components won't be oriented properly by the layout manager.` - if you set the layout manager of the label they will. Given that the above code paints the image at its original size, it is if fact better to use a JLabel because now the label will have a preferred size of the image and the frame will display and pack() properly. So in this case I would just use a JLabel. When you do custom painting you are also responsible for determine the preferred size of the component. I would only use custom painting if you need to scale/tile the background image.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below methods on your button :

```
b1.setBorderPainted(false);
b1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
b1.setFocusPainted(false);
b1.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Good call. That's the technique I used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) which forms 5 buttons and 4 labels from a single image (check the link, it's not as illogical as it may sound).