# Is there any way to make a translucent JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Just wondering, I know you can make a transparent `JButton`, but I want to add an image in the background and have a button that's translucent, AKA able to slightly see through it, maybe a blur?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585867/transparent-jbutton/4586003

Comment: Set the button undecorated and use a translucent PNG as an icon (or icons for standard, hover, pressed etc.).